# SwiftUI NavigationLink selection, bind custom style to touch down/mouse down

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In the below (contrived) example *running on macOS*, the custom Label foregroundColor goes from blue to white upon selection after a brief delay, while the standard label goes from the primary color to white immediately. Is there any way to have the custom color switch immediately when the background flips to orange (which corresponds to mouse down/touch down)? Similarly if one of the items is long pressed it will not be marked as "selected", but on the standard Label it will still flip to white, while on the custom it will stay blue. How can I bind to the "mouse down"/"touch down" state of the item in such a way that I could have the custom blue color behave the same as the standard (e.g. flip to white immediately like the others)?

```
struct ExampleList: View {
  @State private var selected: String?
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail 1"), tag: "1", selection: $selected) {
        Label("Item 1", systemImage: "tag")
      }
      NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail 2"), tag: "2", selection: $selected) {
        Label("Item 2", systemImage: "tag")
      }
      NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail 3"), tag: "3", selection: $selected) {
        Label {
          Text("Item 3")
        } icon: {
          Image(systemName: "tag").foregroundColor(selected == "3" ? nil : .blue)
        }
      }
    }
    .listStyle(.sidebar)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Provided code does not give behavior on screenshot. Needed minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Apologies, should have clarified that this only occurs *on macOS*. Question updated. The screen capture is literally of the provided code run on macOS.